# No Activity Found to handle intent com.bn.sdk.shop.details

Tags: android, nook-tablet

I am trying to integrate NOOK Shop Details API into a nook app. I have used the following sample to integrate [nook shop api](https://nookdeveloper.zendesk.com/entries/20107613-shop-api)

However when ever I run the sample shop API in the nookColor or NookHD emulator . I get 
No Activity Found to handle intent com.bn.sdk.shop.details and the app crashes. Can anybody point out what is missing. I currently don't have an actual nook device to test. Will this work on an actual device?

Thanks a ton.

Comment: I think you should give the path of your package instead of the default one

Comment: Have you tried it on a real device?  The emulator might not have the nook shop app installed.

Comment: No unfortunately I don't have the nook device right now. So I guess it will run ok on the real device then?. I just wanted to double check if I had anything missing before I submit to the Storefront